# Python - How to handle none type in filters with Mongoengine?

Tags: python, django

I have a basic program to filter a list.

```
if request.data["isToday"] == True:
   today = datetime.date.today()
else:
   today = None

get_posts = Posts.objects(
                    Q(title__contains   = request.data["searchQuery"]) &
                    Q(post_date          =  today ))
```

if the date is passed it works fine. when `None` is passed it returns an empty list. Basically if `today=None` i want to show all the posts, if searchQuery is given then both the filters has to be applied.

Am i missing some basic logic here?

Comment: What you're missing is that you simply don't add the condition where you don't need it. So instead, build the query itself within the `if` statement, adding the filter where you actually want it and simply leaving the other query options alone where you don't want it.

Comment: dint get it.. can you show me an example?

Comment: Well someone kind of has. But you could simplify with just the general query `query = Q(title__contains  = request.data["searchQuery"])` and then only within the `if` condition you do `request.data["isToday"] == True: query = query &&  Q(post_date = datetime.date.today())` and then of course `Post.objects(query)` after all that. Which is pretty much how we do it everywhere else.

Comment: yea.. worked like a charm! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can add one check and alter query.

```
if request.data["isToday"] == True:
    today = datetime.date.today()
else:
    today = None

if today:
    get_posts = Posts.objects(
                Q(title__contains   = request.data["searchQuery"]) &
                Q(post_date          =  today ))
if not today:
    get_posts = Posts.objects.all()
```

Comment: this is not what i was looking for.

Comment: according to "Basically if today=None i want to show all the posts"  This is the solution